# Getting Blank Screen while taking screenshots using screencap utility

Tags: android

I m taking screen shots of android device from my app,in my huawei device there was no screencap utility ,but now i have added it by taking it from other device,now i can capture screen using screencap but only notification bar is visible,rest image is blank.

Answer (score 0):

```
adb shell /system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/img.png this is a shell command take screenshot simple and fast

Try this

Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);
OutputStream  os = sh.getOutputStream();
os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/sdcard/img.png").getBytes("ASCII"));
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            sh.waitFor();
```

Comment: i have implemented same code,but getting blank screen problem